# Angular JS function doesn't call from html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to develop a responsive web view. In this html source, I am using angular js. 
I am trying to call a function from html source.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: you dont have any function you just have definition of controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using C# in an JavaScript file. Angularjs is based on JavaScript and the code in app.js should be JavaScript.

Read about Angularjs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/)

Answer (score 0):

You are not making any route in your code to use that controller in.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: "pages/home.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    })

    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    })

});
```